# Laravel issue with controller and variables

Tags: parameters, laravel, controller, routes

In Laravel, I am trying to pass parameters from a controller to blade but with little luck.

route.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

    Route::resource('courses','CourseController');

});
```

Coursecontroller

```
use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
 class CourseController extends AdminController {
       public function show($id)
        {
    //
       $course=Course::find($id);

       $events = Course::find($id)->events;

       $this->layout->content= View::make('courses.show')->with(array('course'=>$course,'events'=>$events));

       }
   }
```

Course.php

```
    class Course extends Eloquent
    {
       protected $table = 'course';
        public function events(){
   return $this->has_many('Event');
   }
```

Event.php

```
  class Event extends Eloquent
 {
   protected $table = 'event';
   public function course(){
        return $this->belongs_to('Course');
   }
}
```

The problem is this:

```
        Undefined variable: events (View: .............show.blade.php)
```

I can't seem to get any other variable, aside from $course, to pass from the controller and in fact any changes I make to the controller don't seem to have any effect now on the output at all! Even if I return "hello";

I have just emptied the whole CourseController.php but page i.e. /courses behaves  like nothing happened!

(Yes it is the correct controller because I even changed the name to check and then threw error)

Is there some cache or something I need to clear?

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems Laravel (or MAMP server?) cling on to old versions of the controller in the memory, with no warning or consistency, which can drive you crazy when making changes if you don't realise it.

I copied the controller and saved as controller1 and then re-routed to this and heyho it showed the latest changes I had made, very strange and annoying!

So be aware of this ghost in the machine.

Now I can get back to the other issues with Laravel. I'll no doubt be back.

Answer (score 0):

For future cases like this one, just use `php artisan dump-autoload`

It's most likely an issue with autoloaded classes.

Comment: I'm still having issues with this. The problem remains with the variable when I saved CourseController4 as CourseController and the routes etc...it gives a different error as if a different file even after dump autoload.

Comment: you may want to try running "php artisan cache:clear" while you're at it too then